# Do endothermic reactions have a higher absolute change in temperature than exothermic reactions?

Tags: enthalpy, temperature

or does it depend on the reaction itself. I am conducting an experiment and the endothermic reactions have temperature changes of at least 8 degrees while the exothermic reactions have a change in 1 or 2 degrees. Is there a reason for that or is it just depending on the reaction?

Comment: It just depends on the reaction.

Comment: Just so we get this right, the endothermic reaction gets colder by 8 K (or Fahrenheit?), and the other(s) warmer by 1-2? What are those reactions?

Comment: oh sorry, Im measuring it in Celsius. The endothermic decrease by up to 8 degrees celsius and the exothermic warmer by 1-2 celsius. They are five reactions: Sodium hydroxide solution + dilute hydrochloric acid. Sodium hydrogen carbonate solution + acetic acid. Copper (II) sulphate solution + magnesium ribbon. Dilute sulfuric acid + magnesium ribbon. Sodium hydrogen carbonate solution + citric acid.

Comment: Note to answer, just a comment on the way you might think, that seems wrong. There is no absolute change in temperature for a reactiin. Take and treat H of reaction and T of reaction as two different things. You cannot deduced H from a undefined T. Unless the T change you mentioned is that of a calorimeter.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The absolute change in temperature depends on the absolute (not molar) reaction enthalpy *and* the heat capacity of the system (including the solvent and beaker!) in its final state *and* the amount of heat exchange with the environment in the timeframe of the experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the reaction enthalpy.

Both reaction groups have a wide range of absolute reaction enthalpies to cause negligible or huge temperature difference, supposing the system is isolated.

The problem with some highly endothermic reactions is that they often require quite forced reaction conditions like high temperature, so it may be problematic to determine the temperature change directly, e.g. by calorimetry.

The temperature change can be then estimated from the reaction enthalpy of the reverse exothermic reaction and the molar heat capacities.

The reaction enthalpy can be often calculated from tabelated values for particular compounds.

Comment: Can you re-phrase the last part of this answer? It's rather unclear, to the point where I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: @Karl   I have tried to reformulate it.